# Sending SMS from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone but my friend does not. When I send a message, my phone sends it as an iMessage and he doesn't receive it. How do I sort this out?

Comment: Did your friend have an iPhone prior?  If so he/she needs to go here: https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** > **Messages**. Check that the type of message that you're trying to send is turned on (iMessage, SMS, MMS, or Group messaging).

[image]